# Why is svg LogoMonniMobile not visible when the width is 736px?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

This my code: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-dust-k1kcm?file=/src/styles.css)

**CSS**

```
@media (width > 736px) {
  #LogoMonni-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width <= 736px) {
  #LogoMonni-pc {
    display: none;
  }
  #LogoMonni-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

**JSX**

```
import { ReactComponent as LogoMonniPC } from "./logoMonniPC.svg";
import { ReactComponent as LogoMonniMobile } from "./LogoMonniMobile.svg";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className={"LogoMonni"}>
      <LogoMonniPC />
      <LogoMonniMobile />
    </div>
  );
}
```

When the screen size is `> 736px` I show the computer version of the SVG, and when `<= 736px` I show the mobile version, but for some reason `<LogoMonniMobile />` does not appear on the screen. What is the reason and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand the id problem LogoMonni_0 LogoMonni_1 LogoMonni_2 ... if id sv1 are the same as scg2 I don’t know for some reason the browser thinks they should disappear

Answer (score 0):

You cant use logical operators like `<`.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 737px) {
  #LogoMonni-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
  #LogoMonni-pc {
    display: none;
  }
  #LogoMonni-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: firstly, I can, and secondly, even use your version anyway <LogoMonniMobile /> is not visible